# Why primitiveDate is defined in Core Data Utility tutorial?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I am following [Core Data Utlity Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/00_introduction.html) to understand the ground work needed in order to make Core Data work. This utility creates a Core Data storage and saves the process id and run date & time every time it runs. It also shows the details of previous runs.

Everything was going fine till managed object class is defined. It is defined as below:

```
@interface Run : NSManagedObject
{
    NSInteger processId;
}

@property (assign) NSInteger processId;
@property (retain) NSDate* date;
@property (retain) NSDate* primitiveDate;

@end
```

It defines 2 different date properties. Tutorial also defines a method in which `primitiveDate` is set when a new object is inserted.

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert {
    [super awakeFromInsert];
    self.primitiveDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

I don't understand why we are setting `primitiveDate` instead of `date` property. I don't even know why `primitiveDate` is even defined when all we needed was `date` and `processId`. I tried to read between the lines (after reading all the lines), but still couldn't get it. Please can you help? I don't know what am I missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important line is

> The primitive accessors do not emit KVO notifications that cause the change to be recorded as a separate undo event.

in the documentation you quoted. The difference between

```
self.date = [NSDate date];
```

and

```
self.primitiveDate = [NSDate date];
```

is that the former issues the Key-Value-Observing (KVO) notifications, but the latter doesn't. The built-in undo system of Cocoa+CoreData looks for the KVO notification to properly prepare the undo stack. This means that, if you do the former, you can undo that operation from the UI, which you probably do not want.

It's a subtle difference which becomes important as your program become bigger and more mature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how does setting the `primitiveDate` sets `date` also? At no place we are setting `date` but it seems to be set, saved and retrieved correctly?

Comment: In a managed object, a standard accessor `foo` and `setFoo:` for an attribute involve a huge amount of magic. So, when you want to modify the behavior of a managed object, you need to use `primitiveFoo` and `setPrimitiveFoo:` which does not involve fancy magic.  But both refer to the same attribute `foo`. Read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1 .

Comment: Oh gosh! Is **that** it? I thought it is completely different property. Thanks for clearing it out. I was in a burning hell. (these magical things are double edged sword in programming.)